# web.config connection string to different database server

Tags: asp.net, web-config, database-connection, connection-string, database-server

I have two conn strings in my web.config
The second of them connects to external database - the database is on different server than the current website.

1. Is it possible?
2. How do I write my connection string?

I have this now:

```
<add name="newConn" connectionString="server=www.somedomain.com;database=dbname;user id=dbuser;password=dbpass" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

But I'm getting error saying:

*Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'currentdnsserver.com' (using password: YES)*

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection I wanted to establish was between different hosting server (one on Windows, another on Linux).

My hosting provider told me it's not possible to connecto from Windows .NET website to Linux MySQL db. Not sure why but not possible.

Would be possible on the same hosting they said.

Thank you for trying to help @T McKeown

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 questions:

Answers:

```
1.  Absolutely.
2.  You will need to write a connection string that use TCP/IP as the transport.
```

To debug this you should try connecting via the SQL Server Mgmt Studio using the credentials you are using in the conn string.

I assume you are using SQL Server, here is a typical connection string to a TCP/IP enabled DBMS using SQL Server authentication.

```
<add name="conn2" connectionString="Database=myDB;Server=serverNameOrIpAddress;uid=id;pwd=pwd;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect to remote server and this is used alot.
The main thing that you should edit in your connection string is: Data Source.

Example:

```
Data Source=192.166.0.2;initial catalog=books;integrated security=False;user id=admin;password=!password1
```

Data Source: IP or URL of the computer you want to connect
Initial Catalog: Name of the Database you want to use
UserName and Password for the database user you want to use when you working with
the database are required.